# jquery: get the object name?

Tags: jquery, object, click, objectname

I am trying to retrieve the clicked object name through the code below, but I get [object object] only, how can I get the object name?

```
<a href="#" class="clickme">click</a>

    $('.clickme').click(function(){
      alert($(this));
      return false;
    });
```

I would like to get `'.clickme'` as my object name.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

thanks for the help guys. sorry that for not being clear.

I want to get the object name dynamically when I turn this jquery click() into a customised function or a plugin.

so,

```
<a href="#" class="clickme">click</a>

        $('.clickme').click(function(){
          alert($(this));
          return false;
        });
```

I would like to get `'.clickme'` as my object name.

and,

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">click</a>

        $('#clickme').click(function(){
          alert($(this));
          return false;
        });
```

I would like to get `'#clickme'` as my object name.

so you notice sometime I want to get id name but sometime I want to get the class name as the object name.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired result for `<a href="#" class="clickme"> click </ a>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery does have an internal property `selector` that can be used to find what you're looking for:

```
$('.clickme').selector == '.clickme';
$('.clickme').find('a').selector == '.clickme a';
```

However you can't access this within the `click(function(e){})` since you have to reselect using `this`:

```
$('.clickme').click(function(e){
  alert($(this).selector); // alerts nothing
});
```

However, when you create the click function you can assign that element to a variable and reference it within:

```
var $cm = $('.clickme').click(function(e){
  alert($cm.selector); // alerts '.clickme'
});
```

Comment: totally love the last example.  Easy to read and use later in other conditional statements.

Answer (score 4):

That's the class. Not the object name and certainly nothing unique.

You can get it using `this.className` or `$(this).attr('class')`.

If you want something unique, use the `id` attribute and replace `class` with `id`.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't responds to the exact question but to the one I got when I get there - So you too maybe ;-)

Short answer: use "**this.name**" which is the same than "$(this).attr('name')"

Sample:

```
$("*").click(function (event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   // Display the name of the clicked object
   $(this).after("<span> " + this.name +" clicked! </span>");
   // Change the name for what you want (optional - just to show it's doable)
   this.name = this.name + "X";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Name or id?

```
 $('.clickme').click(function(){
  alert( this.id );  // or $(this).attr('name') if you want the name
  return false;
});
```

What it really looks like is that you want the class (though, I'm not sure why since you've used the class as the selector).

```
 $('.clickme').click(function(){
  alert( $(this).attr('class') );
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I had to use e.target.id using the event object as Quincy mentioned

Answer (score 1):

an alternative using the event object

```
$('.clickme').click(function(e){
  alert($(e.target).attr('class'));
  return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks. what happens if it is a id instead of a class. can I make it dynamic. please check my edit above for the explanation. thanks.